# Subdomain that uses Route 53 without migrating parent domain

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, subdomain

I currently have a domain (asoba.co) that is hosted on Linode, and for which I use Linode nameservers.  This site currently works as expected.

My goal is to have an additional subdomain for a webapp that is being served from an EC2 instance.  I initially [followed the instructions from AWS here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html) on this procedure.  The instructions had me create a hosted zone in Route 53
([picture of record set within the hosted zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4OUr.png)) along with appropriate records.  Here I just created an A record that maps the subdomain to the Elastic IP address I assigned to the EC2 instance.

It then had me update the NS records for the subdomain on Linode [like you see in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGGLG.png).

After waiting a few hours, I tested the record set in Route 53, which got the result I was expecting

```
Response returned by Route 53
Response from Route 53 based on the following options.

DNS request sent to Route 53
data.asoba.co.     IN     A
EDNS0 client subnet IP
24
DNS response code
NOERROR
Protocol
UDP
Response returned by Route 53
35.169.115.40
```

However, when I point my browser to the subdomain, I get the "domain does not exist" error.  Same thing when I use the "check my dns" services.

Is there a step that I have missed here?

Comment: You updated DNS records in Linode, but your DNS for the domain is hosted by CloudFlare. Wrong admin!

Comment: Had forgotten that I was using CloudFlare!  Thanks

Comment: @ceejayoz OHAI! [I totally stole your answer.](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1886/how-to-handle-unanswered-questions-that-have-the-answer-in-a-comment-or-edited-i/1931#1931) You're welcome. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I currently have a domain (asoba.co) that is hosted on Linode, and for which I use Linode nameservers.

Unless you changed something very quickly after posting your question, it's looking like Linode isn't being used for your domain:

```
$ dig soa asoba.co

; <<>> DiG 9.11.6-P1-RedHat-9.11.6-3.P1.fc30 <<>> soa asoba.co
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 50883
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;asoba.co.                      IN      SOA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
asoba.co.               3554    IN      SOA     ben.ns.cloudflare.com. dns.cloudflare.com. 2028984216 10000 2400 604800 3600

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
asoba.co.               86348   IN      NS      grace.ns.cloudflare.com.
asoba.co.               86348   IN      NS      ben.ns.cloudflare.com.
```

As a result, you did the work in Linode to delegate a subdomain, but since the main domain asoba.co is hosted by Cloudflare, it's all for naught:

```
$ dig soa data.asoba.co

; <<>> DiG 9.11.6-P1-RedHat-9.11.6-3.P1.fc30 <<>> soa data.asoba.co
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 18272
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;data.asoba.co.                 IN      SOA
```

The pertinent result in the above query being: `status: NXDOMAIN`

So you need to either go to your domain's registrar and change DNS to Cloudflare, and then work with Cloudflare to delegate a subdomain, or go to your registar and switch your authoritative name servers to use Linode.

Comment: I had completely forgotten that I had moved DNS management to Cloudflare.  The Linode piece is irrelevant in that case, and I just need to ad those 4 NS records to the DNS records management panel on Cloudflare.  Gave you the checkmark for answering this question.  Thanks!